# Understanding data received from sensor (Twos complement)

Tags: sensors, acceleration

So I use accelerometer to get acceleration data. However, I have trouble understanding data. I have been reading manual, but it does not help me:

```
The measured acceleration data are sent to the OUTL_X, OUTH_X .....

The complete acceleration data for the X channel is given by the concatenation OUTL_X & OUTH_X
and is expressed as a 2’s complement number.

Acceleration data are represented as 12-bit numbers (left justified).
```

I understand the concept of 2s complement and left justified number spread in this case, however, I am unable to understand how to arrive at appropriate acceleration values.

The table with couple examples is also provided:

```
acc value               OUTL_X           OUTH_X
0 g                      0x00             0x00
343 mg                   0xE0             0x15
1004 mg                  0x00             0x40
-343 mg                  0x20             0xEA
-1004 mg                 0x00             0xC0
```

It would be really helpful if someone helped to figure out how do manufacturers of accelerometer arrive at these values. This is little endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `L` and `H` likely represents `LOWER` and `HIGHER`. So the Numbers need to be read as

```
    0 --> 0x0000  -->      0
  343 --> 0x15e0  -->   5600
 1004 --> 0x4000  -->  16384
 -343 --> 0xea20  -->  59936 = 2^16 - 5600
-1004 --> 0xc000  -->  49152 = 2^16 - 16384
```

Left justified just means that all measured values have the *lower nibble* as `0`; i.e. last Hex digit will always be 0.

Two complement means that to find the magnitude of a negative number, you need to do two's complement once more (or do 2^16 - number as shown above).

From the conversion for 343 mg and 1004 mg, it appears that the conversion formula from the measured number to `mg` is `measured number/16.32`.

Comment: [Two's Complement from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Subtraction_from_2N)

Comment: That is clear enough, thank you, I understood the concepts mentioned, I was also confused, because I was getting 350 instead of 343 in the second example, I guess the reference manual is not exactly  accurate, but i guess 0.343 g is close enought to 0.35. Thank you.